# nginx - serve static content from a subdomain

Tags: configuration, nginx, cookieless

Is there a way I can setup nginx to serve static content from static.example.com - without having to modify all my php files to reflect where to get the images from?

I was hoping there was some trick I can do in the nginx conf files.

Answer (score 0):

this probably belongs on ServerFault, but I think you're looking for something like this:

```
rewrite ^(/assets/)(.*)$ http://static.example.com/$2 permanent;
```

So if your PHP files refer to a file /assets/images/background.png, the calls to that file will be directed to static.example.com/images/background.png

Hope this helps!

Comment: Good answer, but that will only redirect requests. I.e., the browser will still be served links to www.example.com/assets/*, but upon requesting them, will be told that they have moved permanently to static.example.com.